# How to unpack tuples with for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I am trying to unpack the values of my data tuple into the variables in the for loop, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am not sure if I've got the syntax right. The error says they are too many variables to unpack.

```
data=("Kareemah","18","coding")

for name,age,hobby in data:
    print(f"Here is some info about test subject 11.Her 
      name {name}\n"
     f"She is {age} years old \n"
     f"She likes {hobby}")
```

Comment: Did you mean: `name,age,hobby = data`?

Comment: You would need to have a *list of tuples* to both iterate over them *and* unpack them…

Comment: Your `data` is a tuple with 3 elements.  So, if you do a `for ... in` loop over `data`, you will be looping over each of its 3 elements.

Comment: Welcome @kareemahajina to SO, if any answer has solved your question or was helpful please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark or upvoting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one tuple you can do this.

`name,age,hobby = data`

Answer (score 0):

Your touple must be put in a list. This is one way to solve your issue:

```
data=[("Kareemah","18","coding")]
```